# Issue with CUDA installation

Tags: cuda, installation, hardware, nvidia

I have NVIDIA Geforce 260 GTX with driver 341.81 installed.
When I'm trying to install CUDA 7.0 this message appears:

This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware.
You may continue instalation, but you will not be able to run CUDA applications.

What have I do to be able to run CUDA apps on my graphic card?
As I know some modification in .inf file can solve this problem...

Comment: Your card is not supported by CUDA 7.0, it is too old. You will need an older version of CUDA

Comment: Does the older version will work with MS Visual Studio 2013? I'll check it out

Comment: CUDA 6.5 has VS 2013 support and will work with your card